# How to change the number of columns in a table dynamically but still keep the table layout intact?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 'n' column table , the first column is a drop down box , on selecting the options from the drop down, the other columns change. For eg: first drop down might need to display a text box and a button , the second drop down 3 text boxes and a button and so on. There is only one row in the table. What is the best solution to achieve this.

with Sincere thanks,

Comment: If there is only one row, why are you using a table in the first place?

Comment: oh! Without table , How do i do?

Comment: @RoToRa - Thanks for your question!!!.It helped me. I removed the table and had put all the values inside <span> and displayed them conditionally based on the <select> <option> value using javascript&css as 
document.getElementById("spanBox").style.display=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give the table fixed width and if you add a new column you can give this one also a fixed width  or height.

Somehting like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="75">Column 1</td>
    <td width="125">Column 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
    var tdTag = document.createElement("td");

    tdTag.id = "td1";

    tdTag.height="300";

    tdTag.width="200";

    tdTag.innerHTML = "<button>1</button><button>2</button><button>3</button>";

    document.table.tr.appendChild(tdTag);
</script>
```

Comment: @michel: You are mixing up CSS and HTML syntax. In HTML lengths in pixels are written without an unit so it should be `width="75"`.